# Easier distinction between questions and answers during Flagged Posts review?

Tags: feature-request, review

While reviewing [flagged posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged), it isn't always immediately obvious whether a flagged post is a question or an answer.

e.g.

- one needs to scan your eyes at the gravatar on the right to see `asked by` or `answered by` to (and my brain doesn't demux this info very quickly this late in the year)
- and some flag types (e.g. `not a real question` / `not an answer`) do allow the type of post to be deciphered.

But IMO a simple visual distinction such as color or label (`Question` / `Answer`) would make the context switching simpler.

Happy Hatting!